# Form data not getting saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and I'm trying to create a sign-up form. When I click on 'Create my account', data does not get saved to the database. I have added resources: users to my routes file. Is there something else I'm missing?

This is my view (signup.html.erb)

**Sign Up**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :emp_id,"Employee ID" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :emp_id, class: 'form-control' %><br><br>

  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %><br><br>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %><br><br>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my **controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def signup
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    
    if @user.save
      render 'login'
    else
      render 'signup'
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:emp_id, :password)
  end
end
```

Comment: You'll have to permit `password_confirmation` too

Comment: Display errors in the view page, this will give you an idea of what is missing in the form.
`@user.errors`

Comment: Rails includes a nifty little gem called `byebug` by default. If you add the line `byebug` right after `@user = User.new(user_params)` rails will step into a debugger. So reload the page in your browser (it will stall) and then switch to the shell where you are running the server. This will give you an interactive shell where you can can then check for example `@user.valid?` and `@user.errors` as well as look at the params.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Iceman if I permit password_confirmation too, it says "unknown attribute 'password_confirmation' for User."

Comment: @GauravGupta byebug is not working :( undefined local variable or method `byebug'

Comment: What does your `User` model look like?

Comment: @GauravGupta included the User Model in the question (edited)

Comment: You'll have to include the line `has_secure_password` to implement the password functionality, including password confirmation.

Comment: @Iceman Thanks I tried that but it says cannot load such file -- bcrypt. Gem is installed. I even added require 'bcrypt' at the top of the User Model file

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` and then restart the server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to permit `:password_confirmation`

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:emp_id, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

And make sure there are no other validations like `email` presence or that will cause validations to fail

Comment: password_confirmation is not a field in the users table. it just has user_id, emp_id and password. User_id is Auto Increment. And yes, there are no validations

Comment: I know `password_confirmation` is not a field, but it is required as devise checks password and password_confirmation should match

Comment: can you do one thing, just create a new `u = User.new` and check for the validations with `u.valid?` and `u.errors.messages`

Comment: You will get to know what fields are required

Comment: @DeepakMahakale why do you think the OP is using Devise? There is nothing in the question that indicates that.

Comment: that's why I asked for the validations messages in comment

Comment: well that was an assumption

Comment: irb(main):008:0> @u= User.new
=> #<User user_id: nil, emp_id: nil, password: nil>
irb(main):009:0> u.valid?
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):9

Comment: I'm not using devise

Comment: irb(main):011:0> User.create(emp_id:"103",password: "hello")
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  Employee Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `employees`.* FROM `employees` WHERE `employees
`.`emp_id` = 103 LIMIT 1
  SQL (48.0ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`emp_id`, `password`) VALUES (103, 'hello')

   (39.1ms)  COMMIT
=> #<User user_id: 3, emp_id: 103, password: "hello">

Comment: I tried creating a user from the console and it worked. This record got saved to the database!